# Android PIN or Pattern change listener

Tags: android

I have an Android app which shows an icon saying "Device should be secured with PIN or Pattern". 
User then goes to Settings and enables a PIN or Pattern for his device and return backs to the app.
Still the icon is displayed. How do I listen for this event and disable the icon?

The icon only disappears after app killed and restarted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any event listener for such issue.

what you can do is you can check it every time when application `onResume().`

by a little manipulation of the following code.

```
public class LockType
{
    private final static String PASSWORD_TYPE_KEY = "lockscreen.password_type";

    /**
     * This constant means that android using some unlock method not described here.
     * Possible new methods would be added in the future releases.
     */
    public final static int SOMETHING_ELSE = 0;

    /**
     * Android using "None" or "Slide" unlock method. It seems there is no way to determine which method exactly used.
     * In both cases you'll get "PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING" and "LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED" == 0.
     */
    public final static int NONE_OR_SLIDER = 1;

    /**
     * Android using "Face Unlock" with "Pattern" as additional unlock method. Android don't allow you to select
     * "Face Unlock" without additional unlock method.
     */
    public final static int FACE_WITH_PATTERN = 3;

    /**
     * Android using "Face Unlock" with "PIN" as additional unlock method. Android don't allow you to select
     * "Face Unlock" without additional unlock method.
     */
    public final static int FACE_WITH_PIN = 4;

    /**
     * Android using "Face Unlock" with some additional unlock method not described here.
     * Possible new methods would be added in the future releases. Values from 5 to 8 reserved for this situation.
     */
    public final static int FACE_WITH_SOMETHING_ELSE = 9;

    /**
     * Android using "Pattern" unlock method.
     */
    public final static int PATTERN = 10;

    /**
     * Android using "PIN" unlock method.
     */
    public final static int PIN = 11;

    /**
     * Android using "Password" unlock method with password containing only letters.
     */
    public final static int PASSWORD_ALPHABETIC = 12;

    /**
     * Android using "Password" unlock method with password containing both letters and numbers.
     */
    public final static int PASSWORD_ALPHANUMERIC = 13;

    /**
     * Returns current unlock method as integer value. You can see all possible values above
     * @param contentResolver we need to pass ContentResolver to Settings.Secure.getLong(...) and
     *                        Settings.Secure.getInt(...)
     * @return current unlock method as integer value
     */
    public static int getCurrent(ContentResolver contentResolver)
    {
        long mode = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getLong(contentResolver, PASSWORD_TYPE_KEY,
                DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING);
        if (mode == DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING)
        {
            if (android.provider.Settings.Secure.getInt(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED, 0) == 1)
            {
                return LockType.PATTERN;
            }
            else return LockType.NONE_OR_SLIDER;
        }
        else if (mode == DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_BIOMETRIC_WEAK)
        {
            String dataDirPath = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            if (nonEmptyFileExists(dataDirPath + "/system/gesture.key"))
            {
                return LockType.FACE_WITH_PATTERN;
            }
            else if (nonEmptyFileExists(dataDirPath + "/system/password.key"))
            {
                return LockType.FACE_WITH_PIN;
            }
            else return FACE_WITH_SOMETHING_ELSE;
        }
        else if (mode == DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_ALPHANUMERIC)
        {
            return LockType.PASSWORD_ALPHANUMERIC;
        }
        else if (mode == DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_ALPHABETIC)
        {
            return LockType.PASSWORD_ALPHABETIC;
        }
        else if (mode == DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC)
        {
            return LockType.PIN;
        }
        else return LockType.SOMETHING_ELSE;
    }

    private static boolean nonEmptyFileExists(String filename)
    {
        File file = new File(filename);
        return file.exists() && file.length() > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you... But in your code where have you used onResume()?

Comment: I haven't my friend but you can, the logic is explained excellently in my code use it for that issue.

Comment: @AlexPierro onResume it's an Activity lifecycle method. You probably should learn a bit more about this before going further https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html.
You have to hook the class Shubham gave to you with your own onResume

Comment: Call getcurrent 

learn about ContentResolver here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - It is not able to identify PIN or PASSWORD

Comment: Check if this helps you - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#isDeviceSecure()

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can check this class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html

This listens to PIN change.

see this link for implementation details 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

A good answer with explanation can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880395/detect-lock-screen-incorrect-password-by-user-in-android).

Comment: For pattern also?

Comment: not sure for pattern but you can get PIN changed using this class.

Comment: Can you do this without being a device owner or policy owner?  Implementing device management is very heavyweight and should only be done if you're pretty much an enterprise provisioning app.